# Регулярка на переименование файлов

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

Есть много файлов примерно такого вида `54757812_a_bb_cc_33_xx_zz.png`, пытаюсь их переименовать в линукс так, чтобы в итоге получилось `54757812.png`.

Использую команду rename с такой регуляркой:

```bash
rename 's/\D*.png/.png/g' *
```

Но в итоге получаю `54757812_a_bb_cc_33.png`. То есть удаляется все, что после `33`.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в итоге осталось `54757812.png`?

Comment: каковы ЧЕТКИЕ критерии того, что должно остаться?

Comment: если вы будете игнорировать уточняющие вопросы, то вряд ли получите помощь. Откуда вам известно, что остаться должно 54757812.png, а не 54757812_a_bb_cc_33.png или не 54757.png?

Comment: извините не правильно сформулировал. у всех файлов цифры в начале разные. должны остаться цифры в начале, а все, что после _ нужно удалить.

Comment: пробовал еще такой вариант rename 's/\D*//g' *
он работает, но тогда и расширение файлов .png пропадает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```bash
rename 's/_.*/.png/' *.png
```

Смысл такой: заменить весь текст после первого `_` на `.png`.

Например, файл `54757812_a_bb_cc_33_xx_zz.png` будет переименован в `54757812.png`.

Comment: да, так получилось! спасибо большое!

Comment: @Deter, обратите внимание, что в ответе использовался флаг `-n`, его указывать не нужно, чтобы файлы переименовались.

Comment: да, я понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\d+)_.*(\.\w+)/
```

Любое число `\d+`, после которого идёт `_`, после которого идут любые символы `.*`, после которых идёт точка с расширением `\.\w+`.
Регулярное выражение возвращает две скобочные группы - любое число и расширение. Их нужно склеить, чтобы в итоге получить имя файла

Comment: не очень понял, как это использовать с командой rename. у меня с такой регуляркой просто выделяется все имя файла полностью. но мне нужно чтобы в итоге осталось 54757812.png

Comment: @Deter посмотри как использовать группы захвата(скобочные) тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/49267932/21358332

Comment: И это может быть полезным https://autotel.co/posts/2021-01-06-linux-regex-batch-file-renaming